# Как следить за процессами в реальном времени с помощью Java?

Tags: java, windows

Как в Java следить за процессами Windows в реальном времени?

Программа должна следить за процессами в фоне, и как только запускается нужный процесс выполнять определенное действие, затем ждать завершение данного процесса. По завершению выполнять определенные действия и снова следить за его запуском.

Вот что есть:

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        // Здесь идет обработка всех процессов
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

В цикле обновлять `Process p` мне кажется неправильно, возможно существует другой способ слежения за процессами?

Comment: Гугл сказал, что существует API под названием WMI process events http://stackoverflow.com/a/550303/2908793

Comment: @Etki по вашей ссылке решение для C#, а мне нужна реализация на Java.

Comment: По моей ссылке можно выцепить ключевые словаи названия, по которым нужно искать соответствующий windows api и его реализацию на java.

Comment: Скорей всего придётся написать свою native библиотеку. Если есть возможность самостоятельно запускать нужный процесс, то можно сделать для этого батник, в котором каким-то образом подать сигнал жаве о запуске. Например создать специальный файл в условленном месте. Уж директории и файлы жава умеет отслеживать. Или пусть жава сама запускает процесс при обнаружение специального файла.

Answer (score 2):

Нормальный способ мониторить системные процессы появится только в Java-9 (смотрите [JEP-102](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102)). Тогда появится счастье, можно будет писать в духе

```
if(ProcessHandle.allProcesses().anyMatch(info -> info.command()
                .filter(str -> str.contains("myProcessName")).isPresent())) {
   // Нужный процесс запущен
}
```

Сейчас, увы, нужны всякие костыли. Есть вариант для винды — использовать [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). Пример кода [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9463010/4856258):

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public class ProcessList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WinNT winNT = (WinNT) Native.loadLibrary(WinNT.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);

        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = winNT.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));

        Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();

        while (winNT.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {
            System.out.println(processEntry.th32ProcessID + "\t" + Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile));
        }

        winNT.CloseHandle(snapshot);
    }
}
```

Мне такой вариант кажется более надёжным, чем периодический запуск `tasklist.exe`.